# Diagrams Net (Draw IO) Link to open local file

Tags: diagram, code-documentation, draw.io

I have a project documentation written in ASCIIDOC with editable PNGs and
I would like to create a link in my documentation that opens a local file directly in draw.io (diagrams.net).

Something like https://app.diagrams.net/file=/home/alex/test.png.
or [https://app.diagrams.net/data={HEX](https://app.diagrams.net/data=%7BHEX) DATA OF PNG}

My first stop was in the documentation: https://www.diagrams.net/doc/faq/supported-url-parameters
but I couldn't figure out how to transform my editable PNGs for the **data** parameter nor how to instruct the application to automatically open the upload dialog.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not possible according to https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/67931